# How to dynamically build multiple dimensional array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

Suppose I receive a number which we do not know before receiving it, say 5, then a series of numbers of length 5: `2,2,3,2,2`.

Then, we build an array`[2][2][3][2][2]`.

Is there a way to do this in Java?

Comment: so build after receive it ??not clear

Comment: Use `java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Class<?> componentType, int... dimensions)`.

Comment: Yes, there is a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of dynamic multi-dimensional array creation:

```
String input = "5 2 2 3 2 2";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
int dimCount = sc.nextInt();
int[] dims = new int[dimCount];
for (int i = 0; i < dimCount; i++)
    dims[i] = sc.nextInt();
Object multiDimArray = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(int.class, dims);
```

Now you just need to keep using [`java.lang.reflect.Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) to manipulate it, since you don't know at compile-time how many dimensions it has.